# Nexus: query all timestamped versions of a snapshot version

Tags: maven, lucene, nexus, snapshot

I would like to query all timestamped version of a snapshot. For example, if version is 1.0-SNAPSHOT, and there are three snapshot builds (1.0-20160913.135022-1, 1.0-20160914.101629-2 and 1.0-20160914.143734-3), I would like to list all three snapshot builds.

I have tried lucene search - it gives all artifacts, but only refers to the snapshot version (1.0-SNAPSHOT), no reference to timestamps.

maven-metadata.xml only refers to the latest timestamped build, doesn't provide details of other timestamped builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got following response from Sonatype support team that serves

> You can use the REST API for this. Specifically the "/service/local/repositories//content" endpoint:
>   `curl -u admin:admin123 -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/org/foo/project/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/`
>
> This will return a JSON response with all timestamped versions in that directory.